# MongoDB Using getters or setter instead of aggregation lookup

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have two different collections, `recipes_db` and `items_db`.

Both of them are pretty easy, **!without! embed documents**, let's just imagine:

*items_db*

```
{
   _id: 1,
   many: other,
   fields: with values
}
```

and *recipes_db*

```
{
  _id: ObjectID("242423423"),
  reagent_items: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

As you may already noticed, the `reagent_items` field is an array that consists of `_id` of documents (items) from `items_db` collection. So if I want to receive one of my recipes with embedded items documents, I should use `aggregation` with `$lookup`.

#### The question is: does it possible to write some kind of working:

- *setter* => which will modify the document on an insert, so when I create a new recipe in `recipe_id` collection, it will iterate over `reagent_items` values, and use `findByID` on each element of the array, and replace (or create a new field) with embedded item documents in it?
- **OR** *getter* => which make `$lookup` to `items_db` collection every time when I request recipe?

I do not seek for an already-done solution as an answer. I ask about: does it possible or not? And if it does, then why nobody (or I have never seen it before) using it, or use `aggregation.$lookup`? Can it trigger any performance issues in the future?

Comment: Why do you need so? Setters and getters are mostly Java-style patterns. You actually don't need them in Javascript. Java and Javascript object models are VERY different. Don't try to apply blindly Java patterns to Javascript. Also, this question is unrelated to MongoDB. You may use whatever techniques with it.

Comment: @Thevs I guess you are missing a point. I am talking not about programming pattern. But about with getters and setter in `mongoose` (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/getters-setters.html) And the question is related with MongoDB.

Comment: You can’t use mongoose getters or setters because both of them are registered at the schema level, consequently, they do not have access to the model instance. To put it simply, you can’t perform a query within a setter or getter. Even if you could perform a query within a setter or getter, the approach you described in the question would be a performance nightmare, just imagine `reagent_items` is an array with about 50 _id values, inserting a document to the DB would mean an extra 50 database trip… I’m very sure you don’t want that.

Comment: @Tunmee Yeah I thought about it too, cause it's a N+1 operation. I have a relative experience with that (I mean N+1 pattern, not mongo getters/setters) in GraphQL endpoint. So I guess the question should be closed right after it.

Comment: @AlexZeDim I'm just telling that getters-setters is an anti-pattenrn in Javascript at all. The presense of this pattern in mongoose doesn't tell something positive about it.

Comment: Yes I have thinking about it all this days and checked couple of articles at Mongo University, so I guess I'll write my conclusion here as an answer, I will also appreciate, if you'll do the same. So I could reward your contribution to this question with plus reputation.